# Installing Django: Using XAMPP's MySQL, MySQL-python 1.2.3 & 1.2.4 errors?

Tags: python, mysql, django, xampp, mysql-python

I am following [this](http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2011/09/14/python-django-mysql-on-windows-7-part-5-installing-mysql/) awesome walk-through on how to install python.

I don't think I have a real problem as ...I think I'm able to work on my django project... however I ran into a couple errors that I just kind of skipped over and I was wondering where they are from.

Everything was going swimmingly until I got to the part where I install MySQL-python. I'm actually using MySQL through XAMPP instead... so if that's the problem let me know.

I tried installing MySQL-python v1.2.3 and got this error:

```
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
creating 'c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-reydf8\MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg' and adding 'c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-reydf8\MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp' to it
Moving MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg to c:\virtualenvs\django_tutorial\lib\site-packages
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\virtualenvs\django_tutorial\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Searching for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz#md5=215eddb6d853f6f4be5b4afc4154292f
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Running MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cnlqlk\MySQL-python-1.2.3\egg-dist-tmp-iaalng
error: The system cannot find the file specified
```

So normally I would expect that 1.2.3 did not install, but I think it did because this command works...

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

So I'm kind of curious what that error message about not finding the system file is from.

I also tried installing v1.2.4 and I get a similar error about finding another file:

```
(django_tutorial) C:\django_projects\insults>easy_install file://c:/users/quentin/downloads/mysql-python-1.2.4.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
Processing mysql-python-1.2.4.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
creating 'c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hz3ivi\MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg' and adding 'c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hz3ivi\MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp' to it
Moving MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg to c:\virtualenvs\django_tutorial\lib\site-packages
Removing mysql-python 1.2.3 from easy-install.pth file
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\virtualenvs\django_tutorial\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.4
Searching for MySQL-python==1.2.4
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python1.2.4.zip#md5=ddf2386daf10a97af115ffad2ed4a9a0
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip
Running MySQL-python-1.2.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0_gfa\MySQL-python-1.2.4\egg-dist-tmp-2ltuob
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
Extracting in c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0_gfa\MySQL-python-1.2.4\temp\tmpemj6wf
Now working in c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0_gfa\MySQL-python-1.2.4\temp\tmpemj6wf\distribute-0.6.28
Building a Distribute egg in c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0_gfa\MySQL-python-1.2.4
c:\users\quentin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0_gfa\MySQL-python-1.2.4\distribute0.6.28-py2.7.egg
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

So yeah. Just kind of curious about those errors and whether or not I should be worried about them. I guess if things are working, I don't really have an problem but... others may also get confused about this and get stuck at the installation/setup part of working in django as well?

***edit***
ok it's not happy when I install 1.2.4, but if I just install 1.2.3 over it, syncdb works again.

MySQL-python 1.2.3/1.2.4

Django 1.5.1

XAMPP3.1.0, Apache2.4.3, MySQL5.5.32

Python 2.7.5 64-bit

Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: you can download MySQL-python windows installer compiled version at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

It means that your `C`and `C++` were not compiled. If you have installed Visual Studio 2012 recently, then follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17065122/1624921), to find the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have resolved the 1.2.4 error.

The 1.2.3 error still shows up but obviously it's talking about a different file. I still find it funny how 1.2.3 seems to work even with the error showing up. Maybe it was misfiring an error message due to a logic mistake or something.

Comment: Ah, I don't enough reputation to upvote... I think I accepted it though.